# How to create np.subtract.outer for arrays in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose `x` is a 2D array where `X1 = [a,b]` and a, b are just scalars

Then for an input like:
`x = [X1 , X2 , X3]`

I want to compute:

```
y = [ [X1-X1, X1-X2, X1-X3],
      [X2-X1, X2-X2, X2-X3],
      [X3-X1, X3-X2, X3-X3] ]
```

Comment: Like `x[:,None] - x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using implicit broadcasting:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_np = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [10, 10]])

X_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None,))
y_tf = X_tf[:, None, :] - X_tf[None, :, :]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(y_tf, feed_dict={X_tf: X_np})
    print(out)  # prints [[[ 0.  0.]
                #          [-2. -2.]
                #          [-9. -8.]]
                #          
                #         [[ 2.  2.]
                #          [ 0.  0.]
                #          [-7. -6.]]
                #          
                #         [[ 9.  8.]
                #          [ 7.  6.]
                #          [ 0.  0.]]]
```